# Determine Tracking Branch in JGit

Tags: jgit

I would like to determine the remote tracking branch of HEAD using JGit.

In straight git, I can do:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{upstream}
```

How can I do this in JGit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
new BranchConfig(repo.getConfig(), repo.getBranch()).getTrackingBranch()
```